# Multiple Subnets Routed Through Separate Network Interfaces Assigned Static Public IP's Going Through a Single WAN Connection

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, dd-wrt

Question moved and completely re-written [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/522155/gateway-router-multiple-public-ips-on-virtual-wan-interfaces-through-single-wa)

I have a block of Static IP's from my ISP and I am looking to setup separate network interfaces inside DD-WRT that all go through the single WAN connection I have. I want to assign Static IP's to each of these interfaces and have separate subnet's and gateway's set inside the DD-WRT router. I would like to be able to access each of these subnet's anywhere on the LAN depending upon the Static information I assign in each device.

Example:

```
1 WAN Port
2 WAN network interfaces (Via aliasing or VLAN's, or any other option)
2 Subnets (Routed separately to each of the respective WAN interfaces)
```

Connect any device on the LAN to either subnet and have that devices traffic routed through which ever WAN interface it is assigned and out of the same WAN Port.

I realize that normally there is only a single WAN network interface that has the physical MAC address of the WAN port, but I'm sure there's a way to create a second virtual interface with a virtual MAC (Random, whatever) and be able to be routed out of the same WAN port. Just not sure how to do it with DD-WRT. Already posted on the forums over at DD-WRT, but haven't gotten a response. Any information is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I cannot have my ISP assign all of the Static IP's to my gateway/router MAC. I have to statically set each network interface. So I essentially need to create a secondary, virtual WAN interface which is routed through the same WAN port, but assigned a different Static IP than the primary, default WAN interface is configured with. This could be resolved with having 2 physical network interfaces and then have them switched together, however, if I'm going to do that, why not just configure it to do essentially just that through virtual interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is simpler than you might think.  If your ISP has provided you a block of static IPs, then step one is to get the ISP to route those IP addresses to your WAN public address.

This one move ensures that any packets destined for your IP addresses will end up at your router.

All that remains is to ensure that outgoing packets are correctly natted to the right public address.

Assuming you use vlans for the internal networks - lets say one of them is 192.168.1.0/24 and another is 192.168.2.0/24 then you can use iptables commands to do the nat for you:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT -o eth1 --to-source 123.123.123.123
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j SNAT -o eth1 --to-source 123.123.123.124
```

These are saying: after routing, if the source is in the 192.168.1.0/24 range, and the destination is out of the `eth1` interface (the WAN interface),  then changing the source address to 123.123.123.123

So the packet would leave your router with one of your public addresses, any replies would comb back to your router because your ISP has said the range is routed to your WAN address.  There it will match the NAT rule and get "unnatted" to end up going to 192.168.1.x.

Comment: The iptables routing seems to be part of what I need, but my ISP doesn't assign/route the block of Static IP's to my WAN MAC. They simply provide the block and allow me to use those. For instance, I have 4 Static IP's available to me - 1 Network, 1 Broadcast, 2 Static/Regular IP's. I have to statically assign 2 network interfaces these Static IP's. I could have two routers behind a switch, however, that would effectively create two separate LAN's.

Comment: I would like to use a single router with only 1 WAN connection and setup some sort of virtual Ethernet interface - similar to the standard WAN ethernet interface in DD-WRT and other routers/devices.

Comment: @t3chman Unless these IP addresses are routed to your internet service, then you won't be able to use them.  You can't just assign them to interfaces and expect that the internet will know where they are.  Your ISP must do this.

Comment: The ISP sets up a statically routed block. End users assign the static IP's to interfaces along with the provided gateway and broadcast addresses in the routed block. I actually work at the ISP and have been working with our administrators, but would like an extra set of opinions on how I should do this. I am in a VLAN that accepts statically setting IP information to network interfaces, as you can do with any network interface on LAN. I know I can set IP's statically, as I've done so and work with advanced networking daily. I just don't understand DD-WRT fluently enough to create a secondary

Comment: virtual network interface that can be assigned an additional static IP, as the primary WAN interface is, and routed out through the same WAN port. I'm sure this can be done with network interface aliasing, as you can with other Linux OS's, just not sure how to do so with DD-WRT specifically - I am open to trying a different OS/FW, but I would like to use DD-WRT if possible. Open-WRT is supported with my router, unfortunately.

Comment: @t3chman The ISP have set up a statically routed block to where exactly? Are you saying you have to respond to arp requests for the IPs?  I cannot fathom why an ISP would set it up this way.

Comment: An ISP has thousands of IP addresses. There are several routed blocks of these IP's - some for DHCP, PPPoE, Static, but ultimately for whatever the ISP decides to use and route the block of IP's as... Each block has a gateway, very similar to on a LAN. The ISP has all of its customers connected across a fiber network. Customer's are provisioned into VLAN's and each VLAN has blocks of IP's which are allowed. If it's DHCP, users authenticate via a RADIUS server which Binds their MAC to a public IP via user authentication credentials. A PPPoE block acts similarly, but is just a different protocol

Comment: as I'm sure you are familiar with. Static blocks are blocks which end-users are allowed to statically assign their network interfaces with the static routing information. The user essentially binds their IP to their MAC (e.g. statically routed). Ultimately, I can assign network interfaces with static routing information, that's not the issue. I just can't figure out how to create a secondary virtual WAN interface. Basically I want two routers in one. I want to route 2 separate subnets, most likely using IPTables, through separate WAN interfaces, but across the same WAN physical port. I could

Comment: just convert one of the LAN ports to a WAN port and just plug both WAN ports into a switch and into the WAN connection coming from the ONT(e.g. fiber box), but why just bridge the two physically, when I'm sure you could do so virtually. I just need to know how to setup a network interface alias, setup the proper routing, and using @Paul's tip with IPTables, route separate subnets through each virtual "gateway" - if you wanna call it that.

Comment: So the answer is yes?  You must respond to arp because it is a layer 3 connection?

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand exactly what you're saying. I set the static IP and the ISP allows the connection. I can have a random unknown MAC set to my NIC and set my IP to anything in the static routed block of IP's, and it will work. I realize that doesn't seem like a normal ISP setup, but that's how it is with mine. It's also completely different because it's a fiber to the home network. But my real question is, how can I setup multiple virtual network interfaces routed out of the same WAN port. I basically want to setup multiple virtual routers inside a single router.

Comment: I've created a brand new question on Server Fault with a much clearer purpose, no one seems to understand the real goal. Thank you @Paul for you iptables tip! [New Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/522155/gateway-router-multiple-public-ips-on-virtual-wan-interfaces-through-single-wa)